# Jquery inputmask "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm"

Tags: jquery, datetime, jquery-inputmask

How to configure to achieve "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm" format?

```
$('input').inputmask({
                mask: "1-2-y h:s",
                placeholder: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm",
                leapday: "29-02-",
                separator: "-",
                alias: "dd-mm-yyyy"
            });
```

This not work, it shows "dd-mm-yyyy h:s" and I can edit only "dd-mm-yyyy".

**[inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)**

https://jsfiddle.net/re4qxxr1/

Comment: Add some code to fiddle with plugin

Comment: @MasterYoda `inputmask` is the plugin name.

Comment: placeholder: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm xm" try replacing it with this

Comment: @GeekBoy it's not working

Comment: Check my answer, I found somewhere on the web

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this will help you:

```
$('input').inputmask("datetime",{
     mask: "1-2-y h:s", 
     placeholder: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm", 
     leapday: "-02-29", 
     separator: "-", 
     alias: "dd-mm-yyyy"
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/53nomjyb/193/

Comment: BTW, why "-02-29" ? Maybe "29-02-" ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally Got the answer, Link i got the answer is 
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/727

```js
(function($){ 
  $('input').inputmask("datetime",{
    mask: "1-2-y h:s", 
    placeholder: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm", 
    leapday: "-02-29", 
    separator: "-", 
    alias: "dd/mm/yyyy"
  });
  
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Inputmask 4.*:

```
    Inputmask("datetime", {
        inputFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM",
        placeholder: "_",
        leapday: "-02-29",
        alias: "tt.mm.jjjj"
    }).mask(".my-fields-to-mask");
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual code for date inputmask:

```
<input class="form-control" required type="text" data-inputmask="'alias': 'datetime', 'inputFormat': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" name="dob" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" value="">
```

if you are using "jquery.inputmask" for date inputmask the below code will help you the date and month are auto corrected like you can't put more then 31 in day and more then 12 in day but year you can enter any thing.

you need to include these first:

```
<script src="https://you site domain/assets/vendors/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://you site domain/assets/js/inputmask.js"></script>
```